# How to supress a "Class may not respond to '-method' warning with variable method name?

Tags: objective-c

How can I prevent this warning with a variable selector name?

```
NSString *methodName;

SEL method = NSSelectorFromString(methodName);

if ([self respondsToSelector:method]) {

    if ([methodName hasSuffix:@":"])
        [self method:dict];
    else
        [self method];

}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use

```
[self performSelector:method];
```

Instead of

```
[self method];
```

And

```
[self performSelector:method withObject:dict];
```

Instead of

```
[self method:dict];
```

Comment: Awesome. You actually solved my next problem! It was crashing on [self method], and now I know why. Wish I could give you more points :)

Comment: Thanks Joris, always happy to help.

Answer (score 3):

sidyll's answer works, but there is a better solution.

Generally, you would declare a protocol:

```
 @protocol MyOptionalMethods
 @optional
 - (void)method:(NSDictionary*)dict;
 @end
```

And declare your object conforms to the protocol:

```
id<MyOptionalMethods> foo;
UIView*<MyOptionalMethods> bar; // it'll be a subclass o' UIView and may implement pro to
```

Then check:

```
if ([foo respondsToSelector:@selector(method:)])
    [foo method: dict];
```

That way, the compiler has the opportunity to fully type check all arguments.  As well, this pattern is not limited to methods that take no arguments or a single object argument.

As well, this is future-proofed against migration to ARC (since ARC rightly complains mightily about the brittleness of performSelector:).

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work with variable method names.

Comment: That is correct, but -- typically -- variable method names are a sign of a poor design.  Not always, certainly.